# Apex SOQL WHERE Clause between two Objects

Tags: apex, soql

I'm new to SOQL coming from a SQL background, and need to create a query that will pull in all Contact records where the OwnerID does not match the OwnerID of the Account.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.OwnerID, 
(
SELECT c.OwnerID, c.ID 
FROM Contacts c
)  FROM Account a
```

I've found lots of examples for "WHERE Name like 'Marshall%' etc, but what I need is to translate this statement in SQL to SOQL:

```
WHERE c.OwnerID <> a.OwnerID
```

I know this is not how it's done in SOQL, and am looking for how to write it properly. I have not found an answer to this in Trailhead, Salesforce boards, etc, and I may not know how to phrase the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

First, go vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0). Second, to get a native query that works, you can write a formula on the Contact record that reads:

```
Account Owner Owns Contact(Checkbox):

OwnerId = Account.OwnerId
```

Then, you write a query like this:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Account_Owner_Owns_Contact__c = FALSE
```

Comment: 8 years for Salesforce to put a community-sourced idea on the roadmap...seems about par for the course.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce world :) You can find many that many years old ideas, still waiting to be responded from Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

SOQL cannot be used to construct complex queries like SQL. You should try something like this, if you need to compare OwnerId between Account and its related Contacts.

```
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, (SELECT Id, FirstName, AccountId, OwnerId From Contacts) From Account LIMIT 5]) {
    for(Contact con : acc.Contacts) {
        if(acc.OwnerId != con.OwnerId) {
            System.debug('Contact record: ' + con);    
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to run this as posted above I get the error "Query has to start with FIND or SELECT."  I get same error if I run this stand alone or with my code above.  Can you point me why I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I tried running the code exactly as you posted it, and got the above errors.  Then I tried to combine it with my existing code:              
          SELECT a.ID, a.OwnerID, 
          (
          SELECT c.OwnerID, c.ID 
         FROM Contacts c
          )  FROM Account a

Comment: Notes do not seem to like code.  The original is posted in the OP.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "Query has to start with FIND or SELECT."

Comment: Possible to post the full code you running?

Comment: SELECT a.ID, a.OwnerID, 
(
SELECT c.OwnerID, c.ID 
FROM Contacts c
)  FROM Account a

for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, (SELECT Id, FirstName, AccountId, OwnerId From Contacts) From Account LIMIT 5]) {
    for(Contact con : acc.Contacts) {
        if(acc.OwnerId != con.OwnerId) {
            System.debug('Contact record: ' + con);    
        } 
    }
}

Comment: I know not correct, but I don't have the hand of SOQL structure yet.

Comment: You need to use the exact code. Where are you using the code and how?

Comment: I did a copy and paste of the code into the Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE not (ownerId like '%yourownerId')
```

Mike, try using the not(ownerId like '%yourownerId') in where clause. It will give you the list that doesn't contain your ownerId.